# How can one extract the appended data of a Portable Executable?

Tags: pe

How do you reliably extract appended data in a Portable Executable?

Comment: (I was asked in relation with [this](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160/how-do-you-reverse-engineer-an-exe-compiled-with-pyinstaller) question)

Answer (score 10):

Just to clarify: the *appended data* - also called *overlay* - is the part of a PE file that is not covered by the header.

[image]

Because of some tricky conditions in the PE file format, it might be difficult to determine in some extreme case, so it's better to rely on a robust library such as [pefile](https://code.google.com/p/pefile/).

Here is a simple Python script that relies on pefile to extract the appended data:

```
import pefile
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(filename, "rb") as s:
    r = s.read()

pe = pefile.PE(filename)
offset = pe.get_overlay_data_start_offset()

with open(filename + ".app", "wb") as t:
    t.write(r[offset:])
```

use with your filename as argument.

---

Personally, I usually do it with Hiew - as Hiew is faster to start than anything else, and also PE-robust:

1. go at appended data start

   1. in `Hex` or `ASM` mode, press <kbd>F8</kbd> to view PE header information
   2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to go at appended data start
2. select until the end

   1. <kbd>Keypad-`*`</kbd> to start selection
   2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to go at bottom of the file
   3. <kbd>Keypad-`*`</kbd> again to finish selection
3. <kbd>F2</kbd> to write selection to file

Comment: You may want to skip an existing Authenticode signature as well.

Comment: no, the Authenticode signature must be last in the file or it will fail validation.  You cannot (any more) append data after the signature.

Comment: There could be a signature at the end of the appended data, so one might not want to select until the bottom of the file.

Comment: if there is a signature then it'll be recorded in the data directory, so you have the start offset and size there, its pretty simple

Comment: https://asciinema.org/a/171993

Answer (score 6):

It is not that hard to do manually.

1. Find the PE header from the MZ header and determine the location of the section table.
2. Walk the section table, and determine the maximum value of `PointerToRawData` + `SizeOfRawData`. (note: these values are subject to alignment using the `FileAlignment` member of the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`).
3. Use the determined maximum as the file offset to the overlay data.

Note that some installers/file formats do not actually use this calculation, but they instead have a small trailer at the end of file which points to the beginning of the payload. For example, ZIP file format works like that - that's why a self-extracting ZIP can be extracted irregardless of whether the unpacker stub is PE, DOS MZ, ELF, Mach-O or anything else.

Comment: no, this is not sufficient.  SizeOfRawData can have any value, even gigabytes large in a small file.  It's bound by VirtualSize at that point.  *Accurately* determining the end of the image is not trivial.

Comment: @peterferrie What would be a good algorithm? I am actually trying to implement one. pefile does it roughly as suggested here.

Comment: @Veitch, my answer to your other question now has sample code and a description, which should be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the [mewrev/pe](//github.com/mewrev/pe) Go package:

```
package main

import (
   "github.com/mewrev/pe"
   "io/ioutil"
   "log"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   file, e := pe.Open("vs_BuildTools.exe")
   if e != nil {
      log.Fatal(e)
   }
   y, e := file.Overlay()
   if e != nil {
      log.Fatal(e)
   }
   ioutil.WriteFile("vs_BuildTools.overlay", y, os.ModePerm)
}
```