# how can file size and PE size cant be equal?

Tags: patch-reversing, delphi

I have an app i embedded another executable inside as a resource to see if the sizes will be different but they aint and using the resource editor i can see the app inside.
as for my target the file size is bigger than the PE size[image: see the screenshot]

i once thought there something  embedded inside the app but how in Delphi?
as a resource i already checked.

Answer (score 8):

"File Size" is the size of the file on disk, according to the file system.

"PE Size" is the value of the [`SizeOfImage` field in the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339.aspx) in the PE file. Its value is calculated as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8197500/5688434):

> `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.SizeOfImage` is the size of the loaded
>   executable/dll in virtual memory. It is not the same as the size on
>   disk.
>
> You can calculate it with `VirtualAddress + VirtualSize` of the last
>   section.
>
> `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.SizeOfImage` is that value rounded up to the
>   value of `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.SectionAlignment` (usually the same as
>   the page size).

`SizeOfImage` can be less than the file size if, for example, the file has an [overlay](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2015/1562) appended to it.

`SizeOfImage` can be greater than the file size if, for example, the sections' virtual sizes are larger than their raw sizes, as is often the case for compressed sections.